# (Groovy) Add multiple values to an ArrayList

Tags: groovy

like the title says, I want to add multiple values to my arrayList in Groovy.
But it is not accepted.

```
Collection<String> actorCollection = new ArrayList<>();
actorCollection.add("first","second");
```

If there is only a single value, it works perfectly.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `addAll`: `actorCollection.addAll("first","second")`

Note: Groovy's list literal will give you an array list.  So could just write `def actorCollection = []` or even `... = ["first", "second"]` to fill the list with the values right from the beginning.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know groovy offered a var-arg overload for `addAll()`.

Comment: @ernest_k yep, and also for an interator